# Is there a way to instantiate a class by its name in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'd like to instantiate a class but I only have its name in a string. Is there a way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is from Delphi help (Delphi 2006, but also available from at least Delphi 7):

**Syntax** 
function GetClass(const AClassName: string): TPersistentClass;

**Description** 
Call GetClass to obtain a class from a class name. This class can be used as a parameter to routines that require a class. The Class must be registered before GetClass can find it. Form classes and component classes that are referenced in a form declaration (instance variables) are automatically registered when the form is loaded. Other classes can be registered by calling RegisterClass or RegisterClasses .

Here some sample code. Works as such only because TButton is a TControl and therefore the typecast is valid.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RegisterClasses([TButton, TForm]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CRef : TPersistentClass;
  AControl : TControl;
begin
  CRef := GetClass('TButton');
  if CRef<>nil then
  begin
     AControl := TControl(TControlClass(CRef).Create(Self));
     with AControl do
     begin
        Parent := Self;
        Width := 50;
        Height := 30;
     end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Great solution. But now I've ran into another issue. The class I'd like to instantiate is a class of my own that implements an Interface.
And registerClass must be called with a persistent class. Any idea?

Comment: Is it possible to derive your class or one of it's ancestors from TPersistent?

Comment: I don't believe so, since it implements a interface and it has to derive from TInterfaceObject

Comment: I fount TInterfacedPersistent, just perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind my previous suggestion.  TInterfacedPersistent is what you want. I thought it existed but couldn't remember the name.

Comment: You don't have to use the VCL's RegisterClass mechanism if you don't want to change your class hierarchy - write your own. Just have a look at TRegGroup.GetClass, TRegGroup.RegisterClass etc in Classes.pas. You can simplify the code by throwing out the RegGroups layer.

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to do that, I Built my own Object Factory that uses a specially subclassed TStringList, I'm currently using Delphi 7 so the string list class supports only attach a Object to a String, then I got to subclass TStringList to make it possible handle Class Types too, so now I can instantiate a object just passing it's class name to the factory. Works that way:

1st - Load a Singleton Object Factory;
2st - Register any object to the factory, could be in the initialization section of the unit;

The main Factory's methods could be: isClassRegistered, registerClass, instantiateClass(ClassName: STring): TObject;

This way I can instantiate any object, or use a previous instantiated object, or even, a subset of they.

I rather use a Enumerated type instead of a string to identify a Class.

Remarks: It's a very, very terse example, a completely functional code is more complex, but,  belive me, not too much.