# How to pass class reference (metaclass) as a parameter in procedure?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

There are two objects: `TFoo`, `TFoo2`.

There is also a class reference : `TFooClass = class of TFoo;`

Both are descendants from `TPersistent`.

They have their own constructors:

```pascal
type
  TFoo = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FC:Char;
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
  published
    property C:Char read FC write FC;
  end;
    
  TFoo2 = class(TFoo)
  public
    constructor Create; override;
  end;

  TFooClass = class of TFoo;

...

constructor TFoo.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  C :=' 1';
end;
    
constructor TFoo2.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  C := '2';
end;
```

I want to create a `TFoo2` object from a string, which is actually its class name : `'TFoo2'`

Here is the procedure, which works fine:

```pascal
procedure Conjure(AClassName:string);
var
  PClass : TPersistentClass;
  p :TPersistent;
begin
  PClass := TPersistentClass(FindClass(AClassName))
  p := TFooClass(PClass).Create;  // <-- here is called appropriate constructor  
end;
```

Now, I want to have similar objects like: `TBobodo`, `TBobodo2`.

And a class reference of course : `TBobodoClass = class of TBobodo;`

And so on...

Now, how can I pass a class reference as a parameter into a procedure, in order to secure the right constructor is called?

```pascal
procedure Conjure(AClassName:string; ACLSREF: ???? ); // <-- something like that 
var
  PClass : TPersistentClass;
  p :TPersistent;
begin
  PClass := TPersistentClass(FindClass(AClassName))
  p := ACLSREF(PClass).Create;  // <-- something like that  
end;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Derive all your classes from a base class with a virtual constructor, and you don't need to pass a class reference

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have it this way in order to create "low hierarchy" objects like TFont, TPen ect.... just wondering, if there is some cute solution

Comment: I guess it depends on whether or not you want a solution that works

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have routines, which save and load TPersistent objects (and all descendands)  into XML. The only weak point is the one procedure, where I have to explicitly use class references to create Classes, what looks ugly.

Comment: Maybe you can use an approach like `RegisterClass`, i.e. create a mapping of base class name to metaclass reference.

Comment: @UliGerhardt even if you did that, you still can't use a metaclass *via a variable* to call a virtual constructor at runtime. The compiler needs to know what the metaclass is at compile-time. In which case, I would probably instead map each type name to a function that returns an instance of that type, and then call those functions when needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to instantiate a class by its name in delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701049/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-its-name-in-delphi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want in Delphi 7.  The metaclass reference has to be explicit at compile-time at the call site, not handled at runtime.

In Delphi 2009 and later, you *may* <sup>1</sup> be able to do something with [Generics](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Generics_Index), eg:

<sup>1: I have not tried this myself yet.</sup>

```pascal
type
  TConjureHelper = class
  public
    class procedure Conjure<TClassType>(const AClassName: string);
  end;

class procedure TConjureHelper.Conjure<TClassType>(const AClassName: string);
var
  PClass : TPersistentClass;
  p : TPersistent;
begin
  PClass := TPersistentClass(FindClass(AClassName));
  p := TClassType(PClass).Create;
  ...
end;

...

TConjureHelper.Conjure<TFooClass>('TFoo2');
TConjureHelper.Conjure<TBobodoClass>('TBobodo2');
...
```

But Delphi 7 certainly does not support Generics.

Comment: I do not have Delphi 9, but your answer helps me to look for another solution for my problem. Thanx....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after some struggles, I found a quite simple solution: metaclass is invented exactly for this purpose!
In your case, you can pass the metaclass as parameter and use it directly without the cumbersome finding class and type casting.

```
type
  TFooClass = class of TFoo;

procedure Conjure(aFooClass : TFooClass); // <-- something like that 
var
  p :TPersistent;
begin
  p := aFooClass.Create;  // it will work!
end;
```

and by calling, you simply use:

```
Conjure(TFoo); // <- for Foo class or
Conjure(TFoo2); // <- for Foo2 class and so on
```

Comment: I tested my solution on FPC thus I think on Delphi 7 it must work, too.

If you just interest in how you can create an instance from a class name then you can follow this thread. The mentioned method using virtual constructor will IMO **not** work. (Tested on FPC, the compiler will generate code for the constructor of the base class, regardless it was declared as virtual or not)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772755/delphi-create-class-from-a-string