# Delphi - Create Custom Form Instance (Having Custom Constructor Create) From String Form Name

Tags: string, delphi, dynamic, constructor, delphi-7

I'm currently confused about creating form using string form name (as in [Is there a way to instantiate a class by its name in delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701049/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-its-name-in-delphi)) but my form has it's own constructor create.

```
//-BASE CLASS-//
TBaseForm = class(TForm)
  constructor Create(param1, param2: string); overload;
protected
  var1, var2: string;    
end;

constructor TBaseForm.Create(param1, param2: string);
begin
  inherited Create(Application);
  var1 := param1;
  var2 := param2;
end;

//-REAL CLASS-//
TMyForm = class(TBaseForm)
end;

//-CALLER-//
TCaller = class(TForm)
  procedure Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
end;

uses UnitBaseForm, UnitMyForm;

procedure TCaller.Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TMyForm.Create('x', 'y');
end;

procedure TCaller.Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var PC: TPersistentClass;
    Form: TForm;
    FormBase: TBaseForm;
begin
  PC := GetClass('TMyForm');

  // This is OK, but I can't pass param1 & 2
  Form := TFormClass(PC).Create(Application);

  // This will not error while compiled, but it will generate access violation because I need to create MyForm not BaseForm.
  FormBase := TBaseForm(PC).Create('a', 'z');
end;
```

Based on the code I provided, how can I create a dynamically custom constructor form just by having string form name?
Or it's really impossible? (I started to think it's impossible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `class of TBaseForm` data type and then type-cast the result to `GetClass()` to that type, then you can invoke your constructor.  You also need to declare your construuctor as virtual so derived class constructors can be called correctly.

Try this:

```
type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm)
  public
    constructor Create(param1, param2: string); virtual; overload;
  protected
    var1, var2: string;    
  end;

TBaseFormClass = class of TBaseForm;
```

.

```
procedure TCaller.Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BF: TBaseFormClass;
  Form: TBaseForm;
begin
  BF := TBaseFormClass(GetClass('TMyForm'));
  Form := BF.Create('a', 'z');
end;
```

Comment: BF := GetClass('TMyForm') as TBaseFormClass; -> Delphi compile error "Operator not applicable to this operand type"

Edit : Modified to BF := TBaseFormClass(GetClass('TMyForm')); -> It works. Thanks a lot :)