# How do I instantiate a class from its TRttiType?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti

I want to create a form given its class name as a string, [which has been asked about before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701049/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-its-name-in-delphi), but instead of calling `GetClass`, I want to use Delphi's new RTTI feature.

With this code, I've got a `TRttiType`, but I don't know how to instantiate it.

```
var
  f:TFormBase;
  ctx:TRttiContext;
  lType:TRttiType;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  for lType in ctx.GetTypes do
  begin
    if lType.Name = 'TFormFormulirPendaftaran' then
    begin
      //how to instantiate lType here?
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I've also tried `lType.NewInstance` with no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must cast the [`TRttiType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType) to the [`TRttiInstanceType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Rtti.TRttiInstanceType) class and then invoke the constructor using the [`GetMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.GetMethod) function.

Try this sample

```
var
  ctx:TRttiContext;
  lType:TRttiType;
  t : TRttiInstanceType;
  f : TValue;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  lType:= ctx.FindType('UnitName.TFormFormulirPendaftaran');
  if lType<>nil then
  begin
    t:=lType.AsInstance;
    f:= t.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(t.MetaclassType,[nil]);
    t.GetMethod('Show').Invoke(f,[]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Once you have instantiated the Form object, you don't need to use RTTI anymore to call its `Show()` method.  Just call it normally: `f.Show;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, on this sample f is a TValue, off course the OP can introduce a TForm helper variable or just cast the TValue  to a Tform  like so `TForm(f.AsObject).Show;`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that `f` was a `TValue`, I was looking at Niyoko's code when I saw that.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `TRttiContext.FindType()` method instead of manually looping through though the `TRttiContext.GetTypes()` list, eg:

```
lType := ctx.FindType('ScopeName.UnitName.TFormFormulirPendaftaran');
if lType <> nil then
begin
  ...
end;
```

But either way, once you have located the `TRttiType` for the desired class type, you can instantiate it like this:

```
type
  TFormBaseClass = class of TFormBase;

f := TFormBaseClass(GetTypeData(lType.Handle)^.ClassType).Create(TheDesiredOwnerHere);
```

Or this, if `TFormBase` is derived from `TForm`:

```
f := TFormClass(GetTypeData(lType.Handle)^.ClassType).Create(TheDesiredOwnerHere);
```

Or this, if `TFormBase` is derived from `TCustomForm`:

```
f := TCustomFormClass(GetTypeData(lType.Handle)^.ClassType).Create(TheDesiredOwnerHere);
```

**Update:** Or, do it like @RRUZ showed.  That is more `TRttiType`-oriented, and doesn't rely on using functions from the older `TypInfo` unit.