# Delphi service locator

Tags: delphi, interface

As I had before in Java, I try to do a ServiceLocator in Delphi. Some code exist but it's didn't work like expected.

I don't want a case with enum or anything else, I want a code that I don't have to touch when I create a new class.

I have a global interface for my application, and all the other :

```
type
  IMyApp = interface
  end;

  IBuilder = interface(IMyApp)
    procedure Build;
  end;

  IPrint = interface(IMyApp)
    procedure Print;
  end;

  ICalculator = interface(IMyApp)
    procedure Calc;
  end;
```

I want a class like that, where I create the implementation directly by the interface, and that the object is create by find it (maybe with RTTI ?) :

```
class function TServiceLocator.Get(aInterface: IMyApp): IMyApp;
var
 C : TRttiContext;
 T : TRttiInstanceType;
 V : TValue;
 ClassNameToCreate: string;
begin
  // Ex: TBuilder (Replace I by T)
  ClassNameToCreate := 'T' + Copy(aInterface.GetName, 1, aInterface.GetName.Length);

  T := (C.FindType(ClassNameToCreate) as TRttiInstanceType);
  Result := V as IMyApp;
end;

var
  b: IBuilder;
begin
  b := TServiceLocator.Get(IBuilder);
  b.Build;
end.
```

Comment: Have a look at the Spring4D framework. AFIK, it contains already what you want to create!

Comment: Thanks, I already use Spring4D, but that's for a company project where I can't use it

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use an ordinary function parameter, have `TServiceLocator.Get()` use a [Generic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overview_of_Generics) parameter instead.

You can then use an `IMyApp` [constraint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics) so that only `IMyApp` and descendants can be specified.  You can get the requested interface type name using the parameter's RTTI (via `TypeInfo().Name`).

You will also have to define a base class with a virtual constructor for your interface implementation classes to derive from.  That way, you have something concrete that you can create from the class type you get from `TRttiContext.FindType()`.  You can't instantiate a class object from just a `TRttiType` alone (see [How do I instantiate a class from its TRttiType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742505/)).

For example, try something like this:

```pascal
type
  IMyApp = interface
    ['{3E8332C3-8C23-481A-9609-8982B66E840A}']
  end;

  TMyAppBase = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyApp)
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
  end;

  TMyAppBaseClass = class of TMyAppBase;

  TServiceLocator = class
  public
    class function Get<T: IMyApp>(): T;
  end;

...

constructor TMyAppBase.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
end;

class function TServiceLocator.Get<T: IMyApp>(): T;
var
  ClassNameToCreate: string;
  Ctx : TRttiContext;
  Typ : TRttiInstanceType;
  Cls: TClass;
begin
  Result := nil;

  // Ex: TBuilder (Replace I by T)
  ClassNameToCreate := 'T' + Copy(TypeInfo(T).Name, 2, MaxInt);

  Typ := Ctx.FindType(ClassNameToCreate);
  if not ((Typ <> nil) and Typ.IsInstance) then
    Exit; // or raise...

  Cls := Typ.AsInstance.MetaclassType;
  if not Cls.InheritsFrom(TMyAppBase) then
    Exit; // or raise...

  Result := TMyAppBaseClass(Cls).Create as T;
end;
```

Then you can do this:

```pascal
type
  IBuilder = interface(IMyApp)
    ['{350FA31A-ECA5-4419-BAB5-5D2519B8BF03}']
    procedure Build;
  end;

  IPrint = interface(IMyApp)
    ['{F726FDDE-A26E-4D0D-BB48-0F639EE34189}']
    procedure Print;
  end;

  ICalculator = interface(IMyApp)
    ['{27E3836B-05B6-4C0B-ABED-C62E6BE194F2}']
    procedure Calc;
  end;

  TBuilder = class(TMyAppBase, IBuilder)
  public
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure Build;
  end;

  TPrint = class(TMyAppBase, IPrint)
  public
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure Print;
  end;

  TCalculator = class(TMyAppBase, ICalculator)
  public
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure Calc;
  end;

...

constructor TBuilder.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  ...
end;

procedure TBuilder.Build;
begin
  ...
end;

constructor TPrint.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  ...
end;

procedure TPrint.Print;
begin
  ...
end;

constructor TCalculator.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  ...
end;

procedure TCalculator.Calc;
begin
  ...
end;
```

```pascal
var
  b: IBuilder;
begin
  b := TServiceLocator.Get<IBuilder>();
  b.Build;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks but the FindType return nil when I search my class or myUnit.myClass, do I need to do something ?